# How do I install Ubuntu Server on my partition when the "Done" option was greyed out completely?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, server, partitioning, mount

Recently, I made three partitions for the hard drive on my spare laptop: one for regular Ubuntu, one will be for Ubuntu Server, and one will be for Windows 10.

However, I ran to a little problem: everytime I try to install Ubuntu Server, select "custom storage layout" and try to mount the partition directly through the installer, the "Done" option was greyed out.

What did I go wrong? Is there any way I can automount the partitions through regular Ubuntu?

I tried mounting the partitions manually through the terminal, and then through GParted.